# Android Input Device Configuration File - touchScreen resolution

Tags: android

I've been making some sort of a touchscreen driver for Rikomagic MK802 iiis, and everything is fine and all, except that the touches are limited only for left half of the screen (if I start a touch there, and move it to the right side, the gesture continues; but I cannot start a touch event on the right side of the screen - it starts registering only when I continue it to the left side).
When I create the input device, I see the following in logs:

> I/Pointer (  265): Device Added: Input Device 92: MT
>
> I/Pointer (  265):   Descriptor: 0db4fb88541bfabf4a688f663d887508d39d703b
>
> I/Pointer (  265):   Generation: 358
>
> I/Pointer (  265):   Location: external
>
> I/Pointer (  265):   Keyboard Type: none
>
> I/Pointer (  265):   Has Vibrator: false
>
> I/Pointer (  265):   Sources: 0x1002 ( touchscreen )
>
> I/Pointer (  265):     AXIS_X: source=0x1002 min=0.0 max=719.0 flat=0.0 fuzz=1.0
>
> I/Pointer (  265):     AXIS_Y: source=0x1002 min=0.0 max=719.0 flat=0.0 fuzz=1.0
>
> I/Pointer (  265):     AXIS_PRESSURE: source=0x1002 min=0.0 max=1.0 flat=0.0 fuzz=0.0

So it's obvious that the AXIS_X resolution is off (should be 1279, I think, because when I add a mouse, its X and Y values are 1279 and 719), but I have no idea how to set it. I think it has to do something with the idc file, but I may be wrong. Please help!

This is my configuration file: http://pastebin.com/gvchTdBS

This is the output of adb shell getevent -lp: http://pastebin.com/BqZUZj7Q (ABS_MT_POSITION_X is 719 because if I set it to 1279, I cannot send any events to the right half of the screen at all)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. 
Getevent is presenting raw events. Android is then doing some scaling according to the screen size. You should set the correct screen size in input_set_abs_params when configuring the touch device.

Hope that helps.